# Euchre question about ranking

Tags: euchre

Played online and saw a situation where the trump was Hearts, the led card was Spades, and the Queen of DIAMONDS won over the Ace of Spades (the led suit).  Which one is it?

I Used to play all the time… but its been a while, and I forgot some things. I’m now playing online and it seems weird. Always told: trump suit first, same color suit second, opposite color last. But the highest led card wins over everything but the trump suit.

Comment: I suspect it was the Jack of diamonds that won the trick.  With hearts as trump, the left bower is the Jack of diamonds, and the second highest card overall.

Answer (score 8):

If a spade is led, then the highest trump played wins. If no trump is played, then the highest spade wins.

Card rank is normal, but with the Jack of trump highest and the same-colored Jack as the second-highest trump.

The off-suit, non-trump queen will not win the trick.

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euchre):

> The player who played the highest card of the suit led wins the trick unless a trump is played; then the highest trump card wins the trick.

> Card rank (highest first) J (of trump suit) J (of same color) A K Q 10 9, sometimes 8 7